# Network-Manager Dbus api RequestScan with wifi hidden essid

Tags: dbus, networkmanager

I'm actually developing a Software using Network-Manager Dbus API.

I would like to be able to request to my wifi device to proceed a scan using a hidden ESSID name.

Here is what I have so far:

```
device_list = NetworkManager.NetworkManager.GetDevices()
for device in device_list:
  if (device.DeviceType == 2 ):# wifi
      device.RequestScan({})
```

I guess I should input the Essid of my hidden network as an input of the RequestScan method but [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/0.9/spec.html#org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless) only specifies me that input is of type a{sv} (array of string value I guess) and no further information.

So here are my questions:

- Is there another way to scan hidden essid using Network-Manager dbus API?
- If my idea is correct, how can I provide my hidden essid to the RequestScan() method (in a similar way wicd dbus api)?